# Autofiltering a column with values coming from a specific range - Error VBA

Tags: excel, vba, filter, range, autofilter

My need is to autofilter a column of an excel sheet with the values coming from a range in another sheet using VBA. This range is dynamic and could include a variable number of rows (each cell contains a different text) that the code should take and use to autofilter the column in the main excel sheet.

Here is the code

```
 Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("RecordTabella")
    
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim srCount As Long
    
    With sws.Range("C2")
        Dim lCell As Range: Set lCell = .Resize(sws.Rows.count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' empty criteria column range
        srCount = lCell.Row - .Row + 1
        Set srg = .Resize(srCount)
    End With
    
    Dim Data As Variant
    
    If srCount = 1 Then ' one cell (row)
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1).value = srg.value
    Else ' multiple cells (rows)
        Data = srg.value
    End If
    
    Dim arr() As String: ReDim arr(1 To srCount) ' 1D one-based
    
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = 1 To srCount
        arr(r) = Data(r, 1)
    Next r
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Applicazioni")
    If dws.FilterMode Then dws.ShowAllData
    
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range("A8:C1000")
    
    drg.AutoFilter 1, arr, xlFilterValues
```

It works great but there is an issue, in case the column C has only one value (one row on C2 since C1 is header) the code should thake the text in C2 and use it to filter, instead it gives me the error "Run time 424 Object required" on this specific part of the code

```
 If srCount = 1 Then 
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1).value = srg.value ' in this part there is the error
        Data = srg.value
    End If
```

Any idea on how to fix it? if the range has multiple rows the code run perfectly

Comment: Replace `Data(1, 1).value` (wrong) with `Data(1, 1)` (correct). Corrected it in the [original answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72231609) code, too. Sorry, my bad.

Comment: Then, you can directly fill a 1D array from the range...

Comment: Declare `Dim arr()` at the beginning of the code. Then use `If srCount = 1 Then` `arr = Array(srg.value)` `Else` `arr = Application.Transpose(srg.value)` `End If`. Then, comment all the lines related to `Data`